# Android Studio multi-dex gradle doesn't recognize java on mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I'm trying to compile a gradle project (plugin 0.14.0) with multi-dex on my Mac, and getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ApplicationContainer:createDebugMainDexClassList'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?
When I execute ./gradlew from terminal, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.
Seems like Android Studio didn't inherit environment path or something.
I ran it from the terminal:

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

And it solved it.
More elegant solutions will be happily accepted :D